# Trouble with DPT in return program

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, eclipse-pdt

Having made a newbe error let me try again.

The website is for a non-profit and I added a PayPal "donation" page couple of years ago; done as a shopping cart (3 types of donations and/or membership). PP returns to a php script that uses the PDT data to build a thank-you page and set cookies for a double-opt-in mailing list. IPN sends the thank-you email, opt-in email, database, etc. works fine.

Now adding a PayPal option to ticket reservation pages. Again, a shopping cart that calls PayPal and seems to work fine in the sandbox; PayPal screen is as expected, and the two foo emails look correct. I pass a different return URL which gets called but bombs on the hand shake. The code is cut&past from the previous effort and based on the PayPal PDT example.

```
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';
    $header = "";

    $tx_token = $_GET['tx'];

    $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";  // see header for def of auth_token
    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    // If possible, securely post back to paypal using HTTPS
    // Your PHP server will need to be SSL enabled

    $fp = fsockopen ($socket, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30); // see header

    if (!$fp) 
    {
       // HTTP ERROR
       mail($email, "PDT Error", "fsockopen error " . $errno . ":   " . $errstr);
    } 
    else 
    {

   fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
   // read the body data
   $res = '';
   $headerdone = false;
   while (!feof($fp)) 
   {
      $line = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    echo $line . "<br>";
      if (strcmp($line, "\r\n") == 0) 
      {
         // read the header
         $headerdone = true;
      }
      else if ($headerdone)
      {
         // header has been read. now read the contents
         $res .= $line;
      }
   }
```

The results from the added echo are:

HTTP/1.0 302 Found

Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

Server: BigIP

Connection: close

Content-Length: 0

The var $auth_token, $socket and $port are set up with a "if ($test)" to switch between the sandbox and live. Obviously with 0 length payload, nothing else works.

I read here that about the new Auth_token. There are some other nits about testing for SUCCESS that I haven't gotten to, with no data to play with..

I can't remember, does the sandbox trigger the IPN? I'm getting nothing there either - set for the sandbox.  Thanks for any suggestions about where to look.

Comment: To preempt some questions ~ it is a business account, Auto return is on, (return URL is given but over ridden with the return cmd), PDT is on, PayPal Account option is on, IPN is on. Adding rm=0 to the call has no effect. The return call seems odd:  http://www.<test domain>.com/tickets/ticketsOK.php?tx=65X28116Y7459360N&st=Completed&amt=15.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=

Comment: I finely gave up on sandbox. PDT and IPN work fine live. It may be that the foo business is not set correctly, but going to the business profile crashes. ~~ Oh well.

Comment: An ideas? not having sandbox makes it hard to tweak the look and content of the "think you" page.